# This place has a big potential to become (or to becomes?) to prestigious

Tags: grammar

Which of these two following is correct? (if they are)

1. This place has a big potential to **become** to prestigious
2. This place has a big potential to **becomes** to prestigious

Comment: Do you mean "too" instead of the second "to"?

Comment: Neither is correct: 1) *become* takes the bare adjective, without a preposition. (Are you perhaps a native speaker of German?) 2) We speak of having ***the** potential to become X*, with the definite article, because the immediately following *to become* clause defines the potential.

Comment: @StoneyB it appears you have answered the question, want to post that as an answer? If not I can expand on what you said.

Comment: @AaronBrown Go right ahead. Posting as a comment waives my copyright!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the verb should be **to become**, not *to becomes*. Anytime you use the form *to + verb* you should use the base verb after *to*.

As [StoneyB said in this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58475/this-place-has-a-big-potential-to-become-or-to-becomes-to-prestigious?noredirect=1#comment111578_58475),

> Neither is correct: 1) *become* takes the bare adjective, without a preposition. (Are you perhaps a native speaker of German?)

In other words, it should be "...to become prestigious." Or perhaps you meant, "...to become too prestigious." That would also be acceptable, since "too prestigious" is an adjective phrase that describes how the place could become.

> 2) We speak of having **the** *potential to become X*, with the definite article, because the immediately following *to become* clause defines the potential.

Another phrase that has become common is "big potential". This is acceptable but less formal. In this case you just need to drop the article *a* to make "This place has big potential..."

EDIT: To make it clear, the acceptable phrases with *have potential* are to have **the** potential, to have **big/great/high/(insert adjective)** potential, or simply *to have potential*. *To have the big potential* would not be acceptable. (Thanks to default.kramer for this comment.)

Comment: I think it's important to note that a native speaker would never say "has the big potential." Acceptable are "has big potential", "has potential", and "has the potential."

Comment: @default.kramer I think even "has big potential" is somewhat problematic.  Potential is usually discussed as though it were a quantitative thing rather than a physical size.  "My daughter's boyfriend is such a loser, he just has no potential." "This town has a lot of potential."  Not small potential and large potential.  I can find it on the internet, but it's not something you hear in conversation, at least in Midwest US.

Comment: @JasonPatterson *Big potential* is certainly in use in both American and British English. How common it is I can't say for sure. [Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+potential&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbig%20potential%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

- The place has a big potential to become to prestigious.
- The place has a big potential to becomes to prestigious.

Both the sentences are grammatically incorrect for the following reasons:

1. The word  "potential" is an uncountable noun; it doesn't need the indefinite article "a".
2. The use of "big" with the uncountable noun "potential" is not correct. You should use "great" instead.
3. The use of a preposition  after the verb become isn't correct; you should not use "to" here.
4. You don't add 's'to a verb when you use it as a to-infinitive; you should say to become instead of to becomes.

You can rephrase your sentence as follows:

"The place has great/a lot of/the potential to become prestigious".